# Robot.createScreenCapture() doesn't seem to match painting operations

Tags: java, swing, awtrobot

I am trying to make a portion of my screen appear blurry. I grab pixel colors out of a BufferedImage where I saved a capture of the screen and draw the pixels again as bigger squares. But this only works when the paint method is called the first time, after that the affected pixels always stay the same even when the content of the screen updates. So it seems that even though the canvas is refreshed at the beginning of the paint method, the robot still sees the screen as it was previously...

```
@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    screen = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

    int gap = 10; int width = 1920;
    for (int r = 120; r <= 420; r += gap) {
        for (int c = 500; c <= width - 500; c += gap) {
            g.setColor(new Color(screen.getRGB(c, r)));
            g.fillRect(c, r, gap, gap);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried clearing the painted area using clearRect() and sleeping the Thread at different positions, but it didn't work. Where do I need to put the createScreenCapture() so the painting actually updates?

This is the whole class:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Transparent extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    private JFrame frame;
    private Robot robot;
    private BufferedImage screen;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Transparent();
}

public Transparent() {
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    frame = new JFrame();
    init();
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setBackground(new Color(0, true));
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    new Thread(this).start();
}

public void init() {
    setBackground(new Color(0, true));
    setOpaque(false);
}

@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    screen = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

    int gap = 5; int width = 1920;
    for (int r = 120; r <= 420; r += gap) {
        for (int c = 500; c <= width - 500; c += gap) {
            g.setColor(new Color(screen.getRGB(c, r)));
            g.fillRect(c, r, gap, gap);
        }
    }
}

@Override public void run() {
    while (true) {
        repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Instead of capturing the entire screen, why not convert the components bounds to the screen context and captur only the area you need?

Comment: Also, bluring is pretty expensive, you may want to buffer the result until it changes...

Answer (score 0):

A number of things pop out at me...

- You seem to be capturing the who screen, but are't taking into account were the window may actually be positioned and what area it might be covering
- When you capture the screen, you component is going to be on it...

Now, this is a very simple example.  I demonstrates how to convert the area of your panel to the screen coordinates and capture only that area.  It does this by first hiding the window and then taking a snap shot of it before re-showing the window and painting the resulting snap-shot...

[image: Snapshot]

```
import com.jhlabs.image.GaussianFilter;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyBoundsAdapter;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    JPanel outter = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    outter.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
                    outter.add(new TestPane());

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(outter);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (AWTException | HeadlessException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Robot bot;
        private BufferedImage snapShot;
        private Point lastSnapShot;

        public TestPane() throws AWTException {
            bot = new Robot();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        public void updateSnapshot() {

            Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
            Point p = new Point(0, 0);
            SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, this);
            bounds.setLocation(p);

            if (lastSnapShot == null || !lastSnapShot.equals(p)) {

                lastSnapShot = p;
                Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);

                window.addHierarchyListener(new HierarchyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e) {
                        if (!window.isVisible()) {
                            e.getComponent().removeHierarchyListener(this);

                            snapShot = bot.createScreenCapture(bounds);
                            snapShot = generateBlur(snapShot, 10);

                            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    window.setVisible(true);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
                window.setVisible(false);
            }

        }

        public BufferedImage generateBlur(BufferedImage imgSource, int size) {

            GaussianFilter filter = new GaussianFilter(size);

            int imgWidth = imgSource.getWidth();
            int imgHeight = imgSource.getHeight();

            BufferedImage imgBlur = createCompatibleImage(imgWidth, imgHeight, Transparency.OPAQUE);
            Graphics2D g2 = imgBlur.createGraphics();

            g2.drawImage(imgSource, 0, 0, null);
            g2.dispose();

            imgBlur = filter.filter(imgBlur, null);

            return imgBlur;

        }

        public BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(int width, int height, int transparency) {

            GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();

            BufferedImage image = gc.createCompatibleImage(width, height, transparency);
            image.coerceData(true);
            return image;

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (snapShot == null) {
                updateSnapshot();
            }
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            g2d.drawImage(snapShot, 0, 0, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

This example takes advantage of [JH Lab's Filters](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html), cause I'm to lazy to create my own...